# Not return nested objects

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, orm, typeorm

I hav a problem with typeorm, I ahve na `queryBuilder` like below:

```
        const projects = await this.conn.getRepository(UserProjectRelations).createQueryBuilder("userProject")
            .innerJoin("userProject.userId", "user", "user.id = :userId", { userId: currentUser.id })
            .leftJoinAndSelect("userProject.projectId", "project")
          

        return await projects.getRawOne();
```

why this query return me this data:

```
RowDataPacket {
  userProject_id: 67,
  userProject_status: 'Owner',
  userProject_lastUpdate: 2021-03-24T21:13:32.000Z,
  project_id: 21,
  project_name: 'nest',
  project_appName: 'Test123!',
  project_createdAt: 2021-03-24T20:47:40.000Z,
  project_shortDescription: null,
}
```

instead of this:

```
{
    userProject: {
      "id":67,
      "status":"Owner",
      "lastUpdate":"..."
    },
    project: {
      "name":"test",
      "appName":"Test123!",
      "createdAt": "..."
    }
}
```

i need to return nested object instead of using alias, can someone tell me how to do this with using `queryBuilder`?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `getOne` not `getRawOne`.